# ES6: tagged templates for nested html tags

Tags: javascript, html, tagged-templates

I'm newly learning JavaScript and experimenting its tagged template literals.

```
<p> Handlebars? Tagged template literals? <span> That is a question. </span> </p>
```

Above is HTML code. I want to achieve with below code the similar outcome but allow the possibility that be able to replace the variables `str` and `quote` as arrays.

```
str = 'Handlebars? Tagged template literals?'
quote = 'That is a question.'

const renderMe = htmlString
`<p>
  ${str}
      <span>
        ${quote}
      </span>
</p>`

function htmlString(string, ...exp1) {
  return () => {
    const p = document.createElement("p")
    p.textContent = exp1[0]

    const span = document.createElement("span")
    span.textContent = exp1[1]

    return p  //but how about span???
  }
}

document.body.appendChild(renderMe())
```

As you can see, I'm stuck at the return stage. So what can be done to improve the code?

Comment: It seems you are completely ignoring the HTML elements that are used in the template literal. I.e. what if the template literal does not contain `<p>` or `<span>`?

Comment: @FelixKling I tried to use ${p} before but failed.....because the htmlString function here did not accept me to put an argument inside document.createElement(). But that probably solvable just I'm not good at coding yet lol. Or I misunderstood your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to append `span` to `p`, **after** setting the content:

```
function htmlString(string, ...exp1) {
  return () => {
    const p = document.createElement("p")
    p.textContent = exp1[0]

    const span = document.createElement("span")
    span.textContent = exp1[1]

    p.appendChild(span)

    return p
  }
}
```

Hope this helps :)